jFrog Artifactory OSS and SBT
I have recently installed later version of jFrog's community edition artifactory (7.77.12).
Majority of my commits will be via IntelliJ using SBT. What I have noticed is that if if I publish to repository sbt-release-local then when I go and view the artifact on Artifactory I do see the published jar, pom etc but the dependency declaration section is empty. If I publish to libs-release-local then I the dependency declaration section shows how to setup for Gradle, Maven, SBT etc.
While not a bust to publish to libs-release-local I am curious as to why it is not working.
Below are the two publishTo's
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "https://somedomain.com/artifactory/libs-release-local")

and
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "https://somedomain.com.com/artifactory/sbt-release-local")


How are the two repos defined in Artifactory? What are their type...?

Not sure how to answer to be honest. If I recall correctly these were standard repositories that were there by default.
Under repositories libs-release-local shows as maven type and sbt-release-local shows as SBT.
